# pre-selected angularjs with ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs

This is my HTML

```
<select ng-model="selectedToggle" ng-change="changedValue()">
        <option ng-repeat="x in toggle" value="{{x.data}}" ng-selected="">{{x.name}}</option>
</select>
```

This is my angularjs

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('namesCtrl', function($scope, $http) {
    $scope.toggle = [
        {data: "orderer", name: "Orderer"},
        {data: "creator", name: "Creator"}
    ]

    $scope.selectedToggle = $scope.toggle[1];
});
```

Im using the **ng-repeat** over **ng-options** is I want to put the ***data*** to value

This line `$scope.selectedToggle = $scope.toggle[1];` will work only if I use **ng-options** is their any way to make a pre-selected while the value of `<options>` will have an `orderer` and `creator`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be like this

```
  $scope.selectedToggle = $scope.toggle[1].data;
```

Comment: You're  welcom. But I think using of `ng-options` is better than `ng-repeat`.

Comment: but how can I make put the value of **data** in `<options>` value in ng-options

Comment: I want something like this in options tag `<option value="orderer">Orderer</option>`